# A Trace Bound Identity of Matrix Products (known for reals) in the Complex Space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, trace

Please refer to [this beautiful paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.636.8021&rep=rep1&type=pdf) on trace inequalities for matrix products. Theorem $3$ of the article (*rephrased*) states:

> For any real $n\times n$ matrix $A$ and any real symmetric $B$ of the same size, let $\bar{A}=(A+A^T)/2$. Then
>   \begin{align}
> \lambda_n(\bar{A})\operatorname{Tr}(B) &- \lambda_n(B)\Big(n \lambda_n(\bar{A}) - \operatorname{Tr}(A) \Big) \\ & \le \  \operatorname{Tr}(AB) \  \le \\   \lambda_1(\bar{A})\operatorname{Tr}(B) &- \lambda_n(B)\Big(n \lambda_1(\bar{A}) - \operatorname{Tr}(A) \Big)
> \end{align}
>   where $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_n$ denote the maximum and minimum eigenvalues respectively.

1. Is this valid over the complex field $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ when
   $A$ is positive semidefinite and $B$ is Hermitian?
2. If yes, will having $A$ and $B$ as Hermitian be sufficient to ensure its
   validity?

The conditions mean that complex matrices $A$ and $B$ have real eigenvalues (trace also) and that $A = \bar{A}$.

While I'm of the thought that this is valid, I need its affirmation or correction. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any Hermitian matrix $H\in M_n(\mathbb C)$ and positive semidefinite matrix $P\in M_n(\mathbb C)$, by unitarily diagonalising $H$, we see that
$$
\lambda_n(H)\operatorname{Tr}(P)\le\operatorname{Tr}(HP)\le\lambda_1(H)\operatorname{Tr}(P).\tag{1}
$$
Therefore, for any complex square matrix $A$ and Hermitian matrix $B$, if $\bar{A}$ denotes the *Hermitian* part (as opposed to the *symmetric* part) of $A$, we have
$$
\lambda_n(\bar{A})\operatorname{Tr}\left(B-\lambda_n(B)I\right)
\le\operatorname{Tr}\left(\bar{A}(B-\lambda_n(B)I)\right)
\le\lambda_1(\bar{A})\operatorname{Tr}\left(B-\lambda_n(B)I\right)\tag{2}
$$
or equivalently,
\begin{align}
&\lambda_n(\bar{A})\operatorname{Tr}(B)-\lambda_n(B)\left(n\lambda_n(\bar{A})-\operatorname{Tr}(\bar{A})\right)\\
\le\ &\operatorname{Tr}(\bar{A}B)\\
\le\ &\lambda_1(\bar{A})\operatorname{Tr}(B)-\lambda_n(B)\left(n\lambda_1(\bar{A})-\operatorname{Tr}(\bar{A})\right).\tag{3}
\end{align}
$(2)$ and $(3)$ can also be rewritten as
$$
\lambda_n(\bar{A})\operatorname{Tr}\left(B-\lambda_n(B)I\right)
\le\Re\operatorname{Tr}\left(A(B-\lambda_n(B)I)\right)
\le\lambda_1(\bar{A})\operatorname{Tr}\left(B-\lambda_n(B)I\right)\tag{4}
$$
and
\begin{align}
&\lambda_n(\bar{A})\operatorname{Tr}(B)-\lambda_n(B)\left(n\lambda_n(\bar{A})-\Re\operatorname{Tr}(A)\right)\\
\le\ &\Re\operatorname{Tr}(AB)\\
\le\ &\lambda_1(\bar{A})\operatorname{Tr}(B)-\lambda_n(B)\left(n\lambda_1(\bar{A})-\Re\operatorname{Tr}(A)\right)\tag{5}
\end{align}
where $\Re z$ denotes the real part of a complex number $z$.