# If $\operatorname{Tr}(H)\ge 0$, is $\operatorname{Tr}(PH)\ge 0?\ $ $H$ is Hermitian, $P$ is positive definite.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, trace

**Old**: Given $\operatorname{Tr}(DH)\ge 0$ for positive real diagonal $D$ and Hermitian $H$, is $\operatorname{Tr}(H)\ge 0$?

Let $D$ be positive real diagonal and $H$ be Hermitian such that $H$ may have negative eigenvalues. Both matrices are of course of the same size $n\times n$.

Given that $\operatorname{Tr}(DH)\ge 0. \ $ Is $\operatorname{Tr}(H)\ge 0$?

---

**Post-edit:**

Thanks @Aweygan for providing a counter-example to the initial question above.
Let's look at it the other way round by letting $\operatorname{Tr}(H)\ge 0$. $H$ is $n\times n$ Hermitian, which may have negative eigenvalue(s).

1. $D$ be positive real diagonal. Is $\operatorname{Tr}(DH)\ge 0$?
2. Let us generalize the question for when $n\times n$ complex matrix $P$ is positive definite. Is $\operatorname{Tr}(PH)\ge 0$?

*I have edited the title to accommodate the changes made.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P$ is positive definite, and $H$ is Hermitian. Take a look at [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3329541/a-trace-bound-identity-of-matrix-products-known-for-reals-in-the-complex-space/3329578#3329578), we have
$$\operatorname{Tr}(PH) \ge \lambda_n(\bar{P})\operatorname{Tr}(H) - \lambda_n(H)\Big(n \lambda_n(\bar{P}) - \operatorname{Tr}(P) \Big)  \qquad (1)
$$
where $\lambda_n$ denotes the minimum eigenvalue, and $\bar{P}=(P+P^*)/2 = P. \ $
The bound can be rewritten as
$$\operatorname{Tr}(PH) \ge \lambda_n(P)\operatorname{Tr}(H) + \lambda_n(H)\Big( \operatorname{Tr}(P) - n \lambda_n(P) \Big)$$
Let's seek the condition on $\lambda_n(H)$ for 
\begin{align}\lambda_n(P)\operatorname{Tr}(H) + &\lambda_n(H)\Big( \operatorname{Tr}(P) - n \lambda_n(P) \Big) \ge 0 \\
&\lambda_n(H) \ge -\frac{\lambda_n(P)\operatorname{Tr}(H)}{\operatorname{Tr}(P) - n \lambda_n(P)} 
\end{align}
is required for $\operatorname{Tr}(PH) \ge 0$ based on the bound stated in (1).

Meanwhile, we know that $\operatorname{Tr}(H)\ge0$ from the assumption, $  \ \lambda_n(P)>0, \ $ and $\operatorname{Tr}(P) - n \lambda_n(P)\ge 0$.

Answer (score 4):

Not necessarily.  Consider the following example:

$$D=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix},\qquad H=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&-3\end{pmatrix}.$$